# how to access function inside controller from web.php using laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to call static functions inside controller class from `web.php.`

**In Controller,**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RoutePackageController extends Controller
{
    static function callingroutes() {
        Route::group(array('prefix' => 'account'), function() {
            Route::get('/userhome', function()
                {
                    return view('welcome');
                });
        });

     }
}
```

**In web.php,**

```
\App\Http\Controllers\RoutePackageController::callingroutes();
```

But it throws exception errors.

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]   Class
>   'RoutePackageController' not found

Answer (score 0):

You should define your routes inside `web.php` like so:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'account'), function() {
    Route::get('/userhome', 'WelcomeController@index');
});
```

No need to define the route inside a controller and then have the controller action inside an anonymous function.

Now we define the controller, note how in `web.php` instead of an anonymous function we passed a string. This string lines up with the controller class name and method.

```
class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 10
In web php to call controller function in **web.php**

```
Route::get('/pathname', [RoutePackageController::class, 'callingroutes']);
```